# Flutter setState() function being called but not doing anything

Tags: ios, function, scope

Managed to create a simple reproduction of an error I've come across in my real program, and I'm not sure why this kind of a thing happens.  I think if I can understand this, it might help me.

The key here is that I HAVE to have the two pieces of the program separated in this manner, and they need to communicate, but that communication isn't happening the way I would expect.  (So please don't suggest I put the timer function inside the rest of the program).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool textBool = false;

  void textChanger() {
    if (textBool) {
    setState(() {
      textBool = false;
    });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        textBool = true;
      });
    }
  }

  Text myText() {
    if (textBool) {
      Text newText = new Text('Original Text');
      return newText;
    } else {
      Text newText = new Text('New Text');
      return newText;
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: myText(),          
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: stateModify,
        tooltip: 'Change Text',
      ), 
    );
  }
}

Future<void> stateModify() {

  Duration waitTimer = new Duration(seconds: 5);
  new Timer.periodic(waitTimer, (timer) {
    _MyHomePageState().textChanger();
    timer.cancel();
  });

}
```

Expected functionality:  Click the button and 5 seconds later it should change to the second set of text.  Then I should be able to click the button again and switch it back.

Instead in this example I receive the following error:

[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called in constructor: _MyHomePageState#a5177(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)

And google doesn't seem to be super helpful on this particular issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `stateModify` function is not a method of `_MyHomePageState`. Also when you are accessing the `_MyHomePageState().textChanger()` in `stateModify` you are eventually creating a new object of `_MyHomePageState()` but not inserting in render tree.

You should use `Timer` instead of `Timer.periodic`. The `Timer.periodic` will repeat the task until the `Timer.cancel` is called. `Timer` will do a callback after the given time period which you require.

Pass the function `textChanger` when you are calling `stateModify` that way you will be able to call the function of `_MyHomePageState` without creating a new object.

Do the following changes.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: ()=> stateModify(textChanger),
        tooltip: 'Change Text',
),

stateModify(dynamic function) {
   Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), function);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are saying, but the entire point of this is that I CAN'T put the function stateModify inside the _MyHomePageState().  Sorry if that wasn't clear originally.  I need to know how to call the function properly without making that change.

Comment: Thank you, that may actually end up helping me.  I'll try something like that out and see if it works.  Either way, thank you!

Comment: Okay, attempted that, onPressed: () => stateModify(textChanger),

And changed 

stateModify(dynamic function) {
Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), function);
}

But I literally have the exact same problem.  Any other ideas?  I understand that apparently “I’m not inserting the new object into the render tree” as you said, but exactly HOW to I fix that?

Comment: The issue is `onPressed: stateModify(textChanger)` in `FloatingActionButton` it is getting triggered even when the value is null. Just change it to `onPressed: ()=>stateModify(textChanger)` it will work.

Comment: ?  Sorry, but in my previous comment I mentioned that that is precisely what I did.  onPressed: () => stateModify(textChanger) As far as I'm aware, that's the only way to be able to transfer data to a function when dealing with things like onPressed: etc.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. The solution works fine for me. I'm able to change the text after 5 secs whenever the fab button is clicked. Do you have any additional code to work with apart from what is mention in the question?

Comment: AHA!  I managed to figure out what I was doing wrong (I was still using a periodic timer at the moment, and the syntax there was incorrect.  That said, I DO need to use this inside a periodic timer, so what would be the syntax there?

Comment: If you want to use inside the `Timer.periodic` you can use  `Timer.periodic(Duration (seconds: 5), (Timer t) => function)`